# Mysql Select data with spaces

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in selecting a data

Sample data

```
" test1   "
"test2    "
"test3"
```

How do i get the data using this query sample?

```
SELECT * FROM `data` Where data_name = "test2"
```

is there a way that it would work something like this. I know the code is wrong but is there a way it would work like this one?

```
SELECT * FROM `data` Where trim_spaces(data_name) = "test2"
```

i don't wan't to use this one because if there is a data_name = "test2 test" it will get it also.

```
SELECT * FROM `data` Where data_name like "%test2%"
```

Comment: Just adding, unless you have a very good reason to store the strings with spaces, you should `trim` them before inserting.

Comment: just wanna make sure the data has no space.i tried to get the data using this query `SELECT * FROM `data` Where data_name like "%test2%"` and it returns a data but when i use the `SELECT * FROM `data` Where data_name = "test2"` or `SELECT * FROM `data` Where TRIM(data_name) = "test2"` i didn't get anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look at **[`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)** function.

**Sample usage:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE TRIM(data_name) = "test2"
```

If you also want to select trimmed values, you can use it in `SELECT` clause as well.

Comment: thank.. i got a problem..i still don't get a value even the value exist in the database

Comment: In that case, we'll really need to see actual DDLs. Consider posting up an sqlfiddle.

Comment: hello..just need a little help..i found the problem..i edit the data on the database. i found out that there was a space on it. so i remove all the space and save it and the `=` is now working. how come does the trim didn't remove it?

Comment: Because you have a new-line (`\n`), not only spaces. Use this instead: `TRIM(REPLACE(city_name, "\n", "")) = 'Abanda'`.

Comment: just wanna ask :) what if the word is `abanda city` with `\n` between `abanda` and `city` how can i compare it with `abanda city` using = then? i tried the replace but not working `REPLACE(city_name, "\n", " ")`

Comment: You have to replace `\n` in both `city_name` and the string you are trying to find.

Comment: like this one `SELECT * FROM `city` Where trim(REPLACE(city_name, "\n", "")) = REPLACE("Abanda city", "\n", "")` ?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45bee2/2

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure you have exactly as many spaces between `Abanda` and `city` in both strings.

Comment: i see..thats why it was not working because of the number of space..well..thanks..